# Vue global word dictionary

Tags: dictionary, vue.js, collections, axios

I have a collection of words in a Dictionary item.
What is the best way to make these words avaliable in my app.

I'm getting the collection from a axios get call.

it is words for default text arround in the app ex. text in button "Send" ..

What is the best way to handle this

thanks :)

Comment: I didn't understand: what do you mean by "available"?

Comment: You can investigate [vue-i18n](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n) for keeping the button texts/labels etc. This way, you also can put the possibility to add new languages aside, but if you'll keep only english values, still ok. You will still have to supply the text file for it beforehand the application runs, though. Indeed, I could not understand the part of your question with the REST call. Do you think creating a json file out of that collection just once? If so, you can use vue-i18n or other file based solutions.

Comment: ex. in my Profil section I have en head text called "Profil information"

I want to be able the do something like
**<h1>{{ dic["profil_header"] }} </h1>**
 @papillon
Make sense ?

Comment: @vahdet Thanks. Yeah, I was think of calling my controller that return an array off dictionary items, one time when the app loads. And then from that be able to use the text around the app.
It should be possible for the editor to change the text in there system and then it should be updated in the app